# Android layout icon , text and subtext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am trying to create a list view that will have an icon and a text in one row and a subtext in another row. [image: for example]

I created a custom adapter to support this and I do get an image, a text and a subtext, however each one is under the previous one.
for example
image
IMDB
account

my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">
        
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />
        
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp"
             />
        
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subString"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to move the image and the text to be under the first linear layout, but then everything is going crazy , and I can no longer see the text or the subtext
any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to use one RelativeLayout, but this should give you the layout in your image:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subString"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Or do you want the layout that you described, not showed? Anyway with the layout that you posted you could only see the ImageView because the nested LinearLayout has vertical orientation and the ImageView's height was set to `fill_parent`... So the TextViews were pushed off the bottom of the layout.

Comment: Hey Sam, this results with really high rows that only shows the icon and do not contain the text. Any idea why?

I am trying to get a layout of:

Icon IMDB in the first row, and account in the 2nd row

Comment: I updated my answer, did you get the latest one? Also how big is the image?

Comment: Hey I did not see your update, this seems to do most of the trick. I think it will look better once I will get the actual image. The current image is a placeholder for a favicon. At the moment is is a tiny 1k picture, and as a result is seems that the IMBD is a little bit over the image, but I think the actual image will solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I do have a follow up. The issue actually remains even when I import a favicon. It seems as if the image is in between the text and the subtext. For example IMDB is above the image, and the image starts and end below the I. Any ideas? I tried to set the margin to be the same but it didn't help

Comment: NVM         android:scaleType="fitStart"       
:)